# Is it possible to accept payments in EMI/Installments using PayPal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I want to use Paypal for processing payments in EMI/Installment,

Paypal subscription feature offers this function to some degree ,
But in Paypal subscription feature the customer can cancel the subscription at any time,

In my case, buyer should not be able to cancel until he/she paid the required amount (in several installments )

Also i am not interested in using Payflow gateway.

Answer (score 1):

Check below links,
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/checkout_exp_installment/

https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/get-started/installment-plan-button

code example:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/html_example_installment/

i think it will help you